# How to run Android project?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to Android programming. I have installed Android SDK and the Android Studio IDE. I have started by reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html). I copied [this](https://thenewcircle.com/tutorials/android/2d-graphics-example.html) code in eclipse and then run my code as Android application. The problem is that when the emulator appears I can't unlock the phone! Also it is too slow and I can't do anything. What are the other options to run Android app?

Comment: The best way to run android apps is on a physical device. Considering slow emulator see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator?rq=1

Comment: I don't have one. How should I test it? You mean anytime I makes some changes I should check on real device?

Comment: It's the fastest way to try apps, however it doesn't allow you to debug on a big range of devices. So you still have to use some emulator. Considering the official android emulator, I suggest one thing: **do not close the window of the emulator**. It takes an awfully long time to start, after start it's still slow but at least you don't have to wait as long each time you want to try your app.

Comment: Thanks Kuba. How should I unlock the emulator?

Comment: Just click and drag the lock icon to the side of the screen.

Comment: It takes long time even to show the screen after Android icon

Comment: Yeah it's quite slow, try to read the tips in the link I posted. But if you are serious about android development, I would highly recommend buying an android phone - think of it as an investment.

Comment: If you are on Windows or Mac (not Linux) you might want to install the Intel HAXM http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

Answer (score 0):

If you run Windows or Mac and your hardware is not enough to use emulator, you may check BlueStacks (http://www.bluestacks.com). It's like a Android player for PC.

Comment: So I write my code on eclipse and then move there and run? Sorry if my question is so trivial

Comment: @sweet you just go to you output apk file (bin/ directory of your project location) and double click it. The app installs in Bluestacks and then you can run it. It has some limitations though (e.g it supports API up to 10).